# Espruino 1.94 on ESP8266 12E does not work

Tags: microcontroller, iot, esp8266, espruino

I'm a newbie to this, so please bear with me.
Trying to load the latest Espruino firmware 1.94 to my ESP8266 12E boards. It came with Node MCU and I used it to flash Arduino programs through it's IDE and Arduino programs worked perfectly.
I have 3 ESP8266 units and tried flashing Espruino on all of them and had no luck.

My Os is Windows 10 Pro (64bit)

Symptoms:
I do not see any flashing errors. All flashing programs seems ends successfully.
Espruino IDE communications Baud rate is set to 115200.
At first connect from Espruino IDE, it says disconnected.
At second connect from IDE, it connects. But on the terminal prompt I cannot type anything. prompt does not accept any text.
I used PuTTY, still the same. I do not see a thing. Cannot type any text at the prompt.

[PuTTY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmaPC.png)
[PuTTY Terminal. No response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgIMf.png)

I used esptool.py to flash the firmware
For python I use Enthought Canopy
firmware I used for my board is "espruino_1v94_esp8266_4mb"
I did a erase flash first. command line for that

```
python "../../esptool/esptool.py"  --port COM4 erase_flash
```

output

```
esptool.py v2.2-dev
Connecting....
Detecting chip type... ESP8266
Chip is ESP8266EX
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Erasing flash (this may take a while)...
Chip erase completed successfully in 8.3s
Hard resetting...
```

Command line I used to to flash to board,

```
python "../../esptool/esptool.py" --port COM4 --baud 115200 write_flash --flash_freq 80m --flash_mode qio --flash_size 4MB 0x0000 "boot_v1.6.bin" 0x1000 espruino_esp8266_user1.bin 0x3FC000 esp_init_data_default.bin 0x3FE000 blank.bin
```

output of flashing...

```
esptool.py v2.2-dev
Connecting....
Detecting chip type... ESP8266
Chip is ESP8266EX
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Flash params set to 0x004f
Compressed 3856 bytes to 2763...
Wrote 3856 bytes (2763 compressed) at 0x00000000 in 0.3 seconds (effective 119.6 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.
Compressed 480292 bytes to 336714...
Wrote 480292 bytes (336714 compressed) at 0x00001000 in 30.0 seconds (effective 128.1 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.
Compressed 128 bytes to 75...
Wrote 128 bytes (75 compressed) at 0x003fc000 in 0.0 seconds (effective 53.9 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.
Compressed 4096 bytes to 26...
Wrote 4096 bytes (26 compressed) at 0x003fe000 in 0.0 seconds (effective 2340.6 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.
Leaving...
Hard resetting...
```

Please help me find a solution for this.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you made any progress to this? i am facing the same issue too.

Comment: Sorry nothing so far :(

Comment: I made progress. Hope this helps you

http://forum.espruino.com/conversations/311589/